# Error creating GCE load balancer: requested address ip is neither static nor assigned to LB

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a situation where Kubernetes apparently can no longer assign an external IP address to a service upon `kubectl create -f Deployment.yaml`. `kubectl describe service <my-service>` reports the following [error](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/cloudprovider/providers/gce/gce.go):

```
CreatingLoadBalancerFailed    
Error creating load balancer (will retry): Failed to create load balancer 
for service default/<my-service>: requested ip <my-address> is 
neither static nor assigned to LB <id>(default/<my-service>): <nil>
```

But `gcloud compute addresses list` indicates that `my-address` is a static IP address:

```
NAME          REGION        ADDRESS       STATUS
<my-address>  europe-west1  <ip-address>  RESERVED
```

And `Deployment.yaml` contains a spec for `<my-service>` that assigns `<my-address>` to a load balancer:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-app
ports:
  - protocol: UDP
    port: <my-port>
type: LoadBalancer
loadBalancerIP: <my-address>
```

What is especially strange: the (almost) same deployment has worked before. I have already tried to [recreate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38684990/1789384) my cluster, but this also did not help. What else could be wrong and how can I overcome the error to make my service reachable from the outside again?

**UPDATE** I have reserved a new static (this time also global) IP address with `gcloud compute addresses create test-address --global` and changed the assignment to LB accordingly: `loadBalancerIP: test-address`. But the same error remains still.

**UPDATE** If I don't specify `loadBalancerIP` in `Deployment.yaml`, deployment succeeds without errors an a new external IP address is assigned to `my-service`. The service can be pinged from outside at this address.

**UPDATE** If I delete my former address with `gcloud compute addresses delete my-address --region europe-west1`, promote the new external address with `gcloud compute addresses create --addresses <ip-address> --region europe-west1`, and then redeploy with the original line `loadBalancerIP: my-address` restored in `Deployment.yaml`, the same error surfaces again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was in `Deployment.yaml` where I was referring to the address under `loadBalancerIp` by its symbolic name rather than the numeric IP address (`NAME` and `ADDRESS` as revealed by `gcloud compute addresses list` respectively). If I use the numeric IP address instead, the load balancer comes up my service can be accessed externally at this address (via the load balancer). ([This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33830507/1789384) previous answer brought me on the right track. I was under the perhaps wrong impression that using the symbolic name had previously worked.)

**Background** Since I was [switching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971385/workflow-for-building-pushing-and-testing-docker-images-inside-gke-kubernete) to an own VM instance (instead of Google Cloud shell) for developing container images, I am receiving `"Insufficient Permission"` errors from `gcloud compute addressess list` on that VM instance. I understand that I could improve this by [recreating the VM instance with scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31928399/1789384) `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute.readonly`. In any case, this restriction apparently had nothing to do with the problem at hand.

Comment: Feel free to accept your answer if it is correct so this question is considered answered and other viewers can see that.

Answer (score 21):

I had a similar problem.  It turns out that if the IP address is reserved as global then it won't work.  I deleted my reservation and changed it to the same region as my kubernetes cluster.   `--global`  I had to use `--region europe-west2` - the same region as my k8s cluster.

**before: fail**
`gcloud compute addresses create my-secure-sftp --global`

**after: success**
`gcloud compute addresses create my-secure-sftp --region europe-west2`

@see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/22721 for more details

Answer (score 2):

You should create **regional** address:

> gcloud compute addresses create my-secure-sftp --region europe-west2

It allocates Global IP for ingress controller (status IN_USE), this is exactly what you need.

Global static and Internal static will not work in your case.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a **regional** address in the same **region**, **zone** and **project** on GCP

I have a problem because I create an IP on a different project that I'm configuring the LoadBalancer.